# Converting shouldcomponentupdate to memo in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usememo

What will be the equivalent code using React memo?

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {

    if (this.props.addCourse !== nextProps.addCourse || this.props.level !== nextProps.level ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `memo` Higher Order Component consumes an additional `areEqual` function that should return the inverse of `shouldComponentUpdate`.

[memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method on class components, the
> `areEqual` function returns `true` if the props are equal and `false`
> if the props are not equal. This is the inverse from
> `shouldComponentUpdate`.

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (
    prevProps.addCourse !== nextProps.addCourse ||
    prevProps.level !== nextProps.level
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```